# Java - Spring Boot - Azure Blob Storage - Status Code 400 - InvalidBlobOrBlock - The specified blob or block content is invalid

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I have to upload large zip file to Azure Blob Storage which contains xml files, each xml file size will be around 200-300 MB. I'm trying to upload the file in chunks using React JS and at the server side I'm using Spring Boot and receiving the chunks and I want to process all the chunks together. But at the `blockBlobClient.stageBlock()` I get 400 bad request with message `InvalidBlobOrBlock - The specified blob or block content is invalid` somewhere while processing. Here is the code that I have written. Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Edit:**
Seems like Stage 11th block in blockBlobClient.stageBlock() is returning 400

**React code: Chunk process and upload**

```
const uploadInsights = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const chunkSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    let uploadedChunks = 0;
    for (let chunkNumber = 0; chunkNumber < totalChunks; chunkNumber++) {
      const start = chunkNumber * chunkSize;
      const end =
        chunkNumber === totalChunks - 1
          ? file.size
          : (chunkNumber + 1) * chunkSize;
      const chunk = file.slice(start, end);
      console.log('chunk no', chunkNumber, 'chunk', chunk);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('filename', file.name);
      formData.append('fileChunk', chunk);
      // @ts-ignore
      formData.append('chunkNumber', chunkNumber);
      // @ts-ignore
      formData.append('totalChunks', totalChunks);

      try {
        let response = await analyticsService.uploadFeatureAnalyticsInsights(
          formData,
        );
        if (response?.data?.success) {
          uploadedChunks++;
          const newProgress = (uploadedChunks / totalChunks) * 100;
          setProgress(newProgress);
        } else {
          console.log(
            `Error uploading chunk ${chunkNumber + 1}: ${
              response?.data?.status
            }`,
          );
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(
          `Error uploading chunk ${chunkNumber + 1}: ${
            error?.response?.status
          }`,
        );
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
    setProgress(0);
  };
```

**Java/Spring Boot**

`uploadInsights(...)` is the method that processes the file chunks

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlockBlobClient;
import com.app.exception.general.AppException;

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Log4j2
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class FeatureAnalyticsService {

    private static final Map<String, List<String>> chunkIds = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static final Map<String, List<byte[]>> fileChunks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static final Map<String, List<ByteArrayInputStream>> chunkStreams =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;

    private static byte @NonNull [] getChunkBytes(@NonNull MultipartFile fileChunk)
            throws IOException {
        return fileChunk.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
    }

    private static void updateChunkIds(String filename, String base64ChunkId) {
        List<String> chunkNumbers;
        if (chunkIds.containsKey(filename)) {
            chunkNumbers = chunkIds.get(filename);
        } else {
            chunkNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        chunkNumbers.add(base64ChunkId);
        chunkIds.put(filename, chunkNumbers);
    }

    private static void updateChunkStream(String filename, ByteArrayInputStream chunk) {
        List<ByteArrayInputStream> chunks;
        if (chunkStreams.containsKey(filename)) {
            chunks = chunkStreams.get(filename);
        } else {
            chunks = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        chunks.add(chunk);
        chunkStreams.put(filename, chunks);
    }

    private static void updateChunks(String filename, byte[] chunkBytes) {
        List<byte[]> chunks;
        if (fileChunks.containsKey(filename)) {
            chunks = fileChunks.get(filename);
        } else {
            chunks = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        chunks.add(chunkBytes);
        fileChunks.put(filename, chunks);
    }

    public boolean uploadInsights(
            String filename, @NonNull MultipartFile fileChunk, int chunkNumber, int totalChunks) {
        BlobClient blobClient = getBlobClient(filename);
        String base64ChunkId =
                Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(String.valueOf(chunkNumber).getBytes());
        updateChunkIds(filename, base64ChunkId);
        try {
            byte[] chunkBytes = getChunkBytes(fileChunk);
            updateChunks(filename, chunkBytes);
            ByteArrayInputStream chunk = new ByteArrayInputStream(chunkBytes);
            updateChunkStream(filename, chunk);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (chunkNumber == totalChunks - 1) {
            List<String> chunkNumbers = chunkIds.get(filename);
            List<byte[]> chunkBytes = fileChunks.get(filename);
            List<ByteArrayInputStream> chunks = chunkStreams.get(filename);
            BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < chunkNumbers.size(); i++) {
                    log.info("Chunk Number {}, Chunk Size {}", i, chunkBytes.get(i).length);
                    blockBlobClient.stageBlock(
                            chunkNumbers.get(i), chunks.get(i), chunkBytes.get(i).length); // error area
                }
                blockBlobClient.commitBlockList(chunkNumbers);
                chunkIds.remove(filename);
                fileChunks.remove(filename);
                chunkStreams.remove(filename);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                chunkIds.remove(filename);
                fileChunks.remove(filename);
                chunkStreams.remove(filename);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private @NonNull BlobClient getBlobClient(String filename) {
        return blobServiceClient.createBlobContainerIfNotExists("uploads").getBlobClient(filename);
    }
}
```

**Errors at server side**

```
Chunk Number 0, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 1, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 2, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 3, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 4, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 5, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 6, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 7, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 8, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 9, Chunk Size 2097152
Chunk Number 10, Chunk Size 2097152
Status code 400, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidBlobOrBlock</Code><Message>The specified blob or block content is invalid.
RequestId:30fc912d-801e-0014-0245-12c1d4000000
Time:2023-11-08T13:16:08.4879527Z</Message></Error>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a limitation from Azure, I increased the chunk size and try to reduce the block stage less than 11 which resolved the issue.